# does bigIP support sticky session

Tags: load-balancing, f5-big-ip, sticky-sessions

Does `BIG IP` support sticky sessions?

I have 2 apache's behind a `Big IP` box at my partner end. Need to know whether `Big IP` supports sticky sessions.

My apache has the sticky session enabled. All requests will hit the backend hosted in `jboss`.

Answer (score 7):

yes it is called session persistance

http://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/lc_9_x/manuals/product/lc_config_guide_10_1/lc_persist_profiles.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference related to session persistence

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. At least we use that feature.

Answer (score -2):

Here are a few related links to AskF5:

Manual Chapter: Session Persistence Profiles
https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/ltm-concepts-11-3-0/ltm_persist_profiles.html

Configuring HTTP Load Balancing with Cookie Persistence
https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/ltm-implementations-11-3-0/17.html

Configuring HTTP Load Balancing with Source Address Affinity Persistence

support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/ltm-implementations-11-3-0/16.html

Aaron

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.